# Can I use code from a stackoverflow answer in a GPL licensed project?

Tags: support, licensing

I'd like to use code from an answer on stackoverflow in a GPLv3 project I'm developing. Is this allowed, as long as I state the original source (URL + username) in the docstring of the function I want to copy?

Comment: The "[legal](http://stackexchange.com/legal)" link is at the bottom of the page

Comment: CC-wiki is a wonderful thing my friend.

Comment: CC-wiki is wonderful, but it doesn't answer the question "is the share-alike clause of CC-SA fulfilled by GPLv3"